# Trying to check if String in Python follows the correct pattern (good formatting)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, match

I have a dataset that contains columns with strings. One of those columns contain a identifier. Now I want to check if that identifier follows this pattern: e.g. AB12CD, so 2 letters(Capital), 2 numbers followed by 2 letters again.

The data is stored in a pandas data frame. I have:

```
for i in range(0, len(data.columns)):
    if data.columns[i] == 'identifier ':
        pattern = re.compile("[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z]")
        if pattern.match(data.ix[i, 0]):
            data['identifier Check'] = 'Ok'
        else:
            data['identifier  Check'] = 'identifier Format incorrect'
```

But this is not working. It puts on every row OK or Corp Key incorrect. Depending on the first row.

Can anybody help me? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't work as expected because `data['identifier Check'] = 'Ok'` assigns `'Ok'` to every row in the `identifier Check` column.

Your code also scans the DataFrame column-wise instead of row-wise (ie it checks the value in the first row of every column, instead of checking the value in a specific column of every row).

My solution defines a function that returns your required output given a string and a pattern.

This function is called using the `apply` method that `pandas.Series` have. In this case it will go over every item in the `data['identifier']` column and send it to the `check_identifier` function. The result of `data['identifier'].apply(check_identifier)` will be an `np.array` that will then be assigned to the newly created `identifier Check` column in the DataFrame.

```
# abusing the fact that default arguments are evaluated only during function definition
def check_identifier(value, pattern=re.compile("[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z]")):
    return 'OK' if pattern.match(value) else 'identifier Format incorrect'

data['identifier Check'] = data['identifier'].apply(check_identifier)
```

An example:

```
def check_identifier(value, pattern=re.compile("[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z]")):
    return 'OK' if pattern.match(value) else 'identifier Format incorrect'

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['AB12CD', 'AB12Cd']})
print(df)
>>         a             
   0  AB12CD
   1  AB12Cd

df['identifier Check'] = df['a'].apply(check_identifier)

print(df)
>>           a             identifier Check
   0  AB12CD                           OK
   1  AB12Cd  identifier Format incorrect
```